# Under which conditions a homomorphism $H\rightarrow G\cdot K$ can be splitted into a product of homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose that $G,H,K,L$ are abelian groups and $G,K\leq L$ (I prefer to use the multiplicative notation for these groups).

Suppose furthermore that we have a homomorphism $\varphi:H\rightarrow G\cdot K$ (i.e $\varphi(h)=g\cdot k$ for some $g\in G$ and $k\in K$).

Under which conditions does there exist a splitting $\varphi_G:H\rightarrow G$ and $\varphi_K:H\rightarrow K$ such that $\varphi = \varphi_G\cdot\varphi_K$? (Note that $\varphi_G$ and $\varphi_K$ are required to be homomorphisms too).

Clearly, if $G\cdot K \cong G\times K$ then such splitting exists for every function $\varphi$. If this is not the case, can we assume something on $\varphi$ or $H,G,K$ that will allow such decomposition?

P.S - please do not post answers such as "It works if $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism", "it works if $G,H,K$ are trivial" etc. I'm looking for a weak condition (hopefully an if and only if) that is easily verified in many cases.

Thanks.